# ActiveRecord query assistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i need a little help with a AR query. This is how my models look like:

```
class User < AR:B
  has_many :publications
end

class Publication < AR:B
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < AR:B
  has_many :publications
end
```

Now let's say I want to iterate over *all* existing categories and either display the user's publications, or display something like "#{current_user.name} has no publications in this category".

```
class PublicationsController < AC:B

  def index
    @categories = Category.find(:all, :include => :publications, :conditions => { 'publications.user_id' => current_user })
  end

end
```

This gives me all Categories the user actually has publications, but lacks the "empty" ones.

Any suggestions? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you all the Category objects:

```
@categories = Category.all
```

Then, if you declare has_many :through associations you can do something like the following:

```
@categories.each do |category|
  if category.users.include?(current_user)
    # User has publications
    publications = category.publications.select { |pub| pub.user == current_user }
  else
    # User has no publications
  end
end
```

(has-many-through declarations:

```
class User < AR:B
  has_many :publications
  has_many :categories, :through => :publication
end

class Publication < AR:B
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < AR:B
  has_many :publications
  has_many :users, :through => :publication
end
```

... warning: drycode)

There's probably an neater way to do this using named scopes though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would i access the publications? @category.publications would still give me all publications of the category...

Comment: Inside the if statement is the publications = ..., that should give you the publications the user has on the category

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to just modify the find call:

```
@categories = Category.find(:all, :include => :publications, :conditions => [ 'publications.user_id=? OR publications.user_id IS NULL', current_user ])
```

Notice that we use the Array variant here rather than the Hash variant, since the example in the documentation implies this is the correct usage.

Comment: This gives me all categories with publications, but not all categories. The condition publications.user_id IS NULL will be false by default, because there are no matching records, or am i missing something?

Comment: I'd need to try it or read the code to understand the SQL that comes out, in the mean time the following may work:

@categories = Category.find(:all, :joins => "LEFT JOIN publications ON publications.user_id = #{current_user.id}")